# "getLocation() method cannot be called from event thread"

Tags: blackberry

I'm developing an application where am trying to get the current location. But am getting an error "getLocation() method cannot be called from event thread" even though I have created a new thread. Can anyone help me out?

Here is my code

```
Thread t = new MyThread();
t.run();
```

and here is the run function of MyThread class:

```
try
    {

        Criteria cr = new Criteria();
        cr.setHorizontalAccuracy(500);
        LocationProvider lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);
        Location l = lp.getLocation(60);
        Coordinates c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();
        if (c != null)
        {
            double longitude = c.getLongitude();
            double latitude = c.getLatitude();
            Dialog.alert("latitude:"+latitude);
            Dialog.alert("longitude:"+longitude);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Dialog.alert(e.getMessage());

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't start a thread by calling the run() method. You start a thread by calling the start() method.

Comment: Even though I use start() method, am getting the same error. Any idea??